# Initialize each instance for each worker of multprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

As container for shared (static) data and the database connection I use a `Worker` class:

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def initializer(self):
        # setting up a database connection
        print("{} with PID {} initialized".format(self, os.getpid()))
    def __call__(self, value):
        print("{} with PID {} called with value={}".format(self, os.getpid(), value))
        # doing something with self.data and write it to the database
        time.sleep(0.5)

def main():
    print("main has PID {}".format(os.getpid()))
    worker = Worker([1,2,3,4])
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=2, initializer=worker.initializer)
    pool.map(worker, range(4))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

However, the initialization is not working. I think it's because `initializer()` and `__call__()` is called for different instances. The output of the above code is as follows:

```
main has PID 5
<__main__.Worker object at 0xA> in main
<__mp_main__.Worker object at 0xB> with PID 6 initialized
<__mp_main__.Worker object at 0xC> with PID 6 called with value=0
<__mp_main__.Worker object at 0xD> with PID 7 initialized
<__mp_main__.Worker object at 0xE> with PID 7 called with value=1
<__mp_main__.Worker object at 0xD> with PID 6 called with value=2
<__mp_main__.Worker object at 0xE> with PID 7 called with value=3
```

Obviously, the location of the `Worker` instance have to change with the process id (PID) because the fork yields a new but duplicated instance. But it's also changing for `initializer()` and `__call__()` for the same PID? Thus, my database connection is not available.

Why is it so? How to do it *properly* without global variables etc. instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per process, you are seeing one Worker which is the copy of your Worker class, and another copy which is the copy of your worker object.

The solution is indeed to use a global. Globals are not shared between processes.

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def initializer(self):
        # setting up a database connection
        global db
        print("{} with PID {} initialized".format(self, os.getpid()))
        db = "set by {} with PID {} initialized".format(self, os.getpid())

    def __call__(self, value):
        print("{} with PID {} called with value={}".format(self, os.getpid(), value))
        global db
        print("Using db {}".format(db))
        # doing something with self.data and write it to the database
        time.sleep(0.5)

def main():
    print("main has PID {}".format(os.getpid()))
    worker = Worker([1,2,3,4])
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=2, initializer=worker.initializer)
    pool.map(worker, range(4))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

produces

```
main has PID 29128
<__mp_main__.Worker object at 0x0000022319997A00> with PID 30832 initialized
<__mp_main__.Worker object at 0x0000022319453AF0> with PID 30832 called with value=0
Using db set by <__mp_main__.Worker object at 0x0000022319997A00> with PID 30832 initialized
<__mp_main__.Worker object at 0x00000167E7077A00> with PID 29900 initialized
<__mp_main__.Worker object at 0x00000167E6B53AF0> with PID 29900 called with value=1
Using db set by <__mp_main__.Worker object at 0x00000167E7077A00> with PID 29900 initialized
<__mp_main__.Worker object at 0x0000022319453AF0> with PID 30832 called with value=2
Using db set by <__mp_main__.Worker object at 0x0000022319997A00> with PID 30832 initialized
<__mp_main__.Worker object at 0x00000167E6B53AF0> with PID 29900 called with value=3
Using db set by <__mp_main__.Worker object at 0x00000167E7077A00> with PID 29900 initialized
```

Answer (score 2):

as another way of solving this, see:

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def initializer(self):
        # setting up a database connection
        print("{} with PID {} initialized".format(self, os.getpid()))

    def __call__(self, value):
        print("{} with PID {} called with value={}".format(self, os.getpid(), value))
        # doing something with self.data and write it to the database
        time.sleep(0.5)

def worker_initializer(data):
    global worker
    worker = Worker(data)
    worker.initializer()

def worker_call(*args, **kwds):
    return worker(*args, **kwds)

def main():
    print("main has PID {}".format(os.getpid()))
    with mp.Pool(processes=2, initializer=worker_initializer, initargs=([1,2,3,4],)) as pool:
        pool.map(worker_call, range(4))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I've left your `Worker` class the same, but introduced another set of helper functions to call into the worker appropriately.  Basically, using `Process`es implies using global state (in the child processes anyway) in all but trivial uses.

Note that the output of this is slightly confusing as both child processes will allocate new `Worker`s at the same address (in their own address space) so will appear duplicated.